# Desplazar una matriz hacia la derecha

Tags: java, matrices

estoy creando un proyecto en el que se generan label de manera automática dependiendo de una matriz.

La matriz contiene notas de alumnos y lo que estoy intentando es crear los label de manera automática en función de las notas que haya en la matriz, eso lo he conseguido hacer, pero el problema lo tengo en el posicionamiento.

También creo unos label de manera automática para los nombres de los alumnos, pero los de las notas se superponen encima de los nombres y no consigo desplazar la matriz hacia la derecha por más dimensiones que le ponga.

Adjunto fuente y captura. Este fuente es del action Performed del botón el cual crea los label de los nombres y de las notas

```
for(int i=0;i<calificacion.nombres().length;i++){
        nombre = new JLabel();
        nombre.setText(calificacion.getNombre(i));
        jpResultado.add(nombre);
        nombre.setBounds(20, 30*i, 50, 20);
        nombre.setVisible(true);

    }
        for(int i=0; i<calificacion.notas().length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<calificacion.notas()[i].length;j++){
                 calificacion.getNota(i, j);
                 System.out.println("Notas : " + calificacion.getNota(i, j));
                 notas = new JLabel();
                 notas.setText(String.valueOf(calificacion.getNota(i, j)));
                 jpResultado.add(notas);
                 notas.setBounds(70*j, 30*i, 50, 20);
                 //notas.setLocation(30*k, 20*j);

            }
        }
      this.pack();
```

[image: Resultado del action Listener]

como se puede observar en la imagen, todo queda a la izquierda y no consigo posicionarlo más a la derecha